# Changing class of a div using jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
<div id="slider" align="center" style="width:50%;margin-left:20%;" >
</div>
<div id="1" class="res1" style="margin:10px auto">
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        animate:"fast", 
        value:0,
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        step: 25,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            if(($("#1").hasClass('res1'))&& (ui.value=25)){
                $(".res1").toggleClass('res1 res2');
            }
            else if(($("#1").hasClass('res2'))&& (ui.value=50)){
                $(".res2").toggleClass('res2 res3');
            }
            else if(($("#1").hasClass('res2'))&& (ui.value=50)){
                $(".res2").toggleClass('res2 res3');
            }    
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I have to change the class of div having id "1" to "res2"(initial class of div is 'res1') when ui.slider value is 25 and to class "res3" when the ui.slider value is 50.I used the above code.But I couldnt get the output as desired.Please help

Comment: First of all, it's not an optimal way of checking element's class on every slide event, first check for ui.value, then for the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var classes = {
        0: 'res1',
        25: 'res2',
        50: 'res3'
    }
    $("#slider").slider({
        animate: "fast",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        step: 25,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#1").removeClass().addClass(classes[ui.value])
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G7dWd/)

Comment: classic example dude... +1 for that

Comment: For anyone not too familiar with jquery (like me) who looked at the Fiddle using IE 11 - it does not work with IE 11. Works with Firefox. I thought IE 11 was supposed to be standards compliant - yet loads of things/sites are broken when using it.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse looks like a problem with jQuery 2, try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G7dWd/2/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if ($("#1").hasClass('res1') && (ui.value = 25)) {
    $("#1").removeClass('res1').addClass('res2');
} else if ($("#1").hasClass('res2') && (ui.value = 50)) {
    $("#1").removeClass('res2').addClass('res3');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$("#1").addClass("res2");`

For full documentation please read http://api.jquery.com/addClass/